# GitHub - Merging other's repo as part of your own repo

Tags: git, github

Background: I am self-teaching networking course via Stanford's MOOC. However, Stanford MOOC doesn't have hands-on lab assignment so I decided to use Princeton university's assignment that is available to public as my assignment. ([Here's Princeton's Network assignment for those that are interested](https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/COS461-Public)).

In this case, what is the appropriate way of merging my currently existing repository (where I push my notes and work on labs based on books) with Princeton's assignment repository? Since I'm not really contributing the Princeton assignment as well as I want to have one single repo, I was refraining from forking Princeton's repository.

Easiest way that I can thing of is cloning Princeton's assignment repository to my local machine, removing `.git` file from cloned repository, dumping the whole content inside my currently existing repository, then pushing. But before I do that, I would like to hear second opinion based on more experienced users. Thank you for you advice in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Since I'm not really contributing the Princeton assignment as well as I want to have one single repo

That means you can push your local clone of the Princeton's assignment repository to your "currently existing repository (where I push my notes and work on labs based on books)" as an orphan branch.

```
cd /local/clone/of/Princeton
git remote set-url origin /url/of/your/current/exisiting/repo
git push -u origin master:princeton
```

That will push the `master` branch of the local clone of the Princeton repo to your existing unique remote repository, but in a branch called "`princeton`".
That new branch will have a separate unrelated history o your current repo `master` branch.